# What determines the number of wifi device?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, dongle

My computer has two wifi receivers. Why is one of them has the number 12? What determine that number?

[image]

Comment: Sequencer. Each time you connect to new network it increases the counter. Means nothing actually.

Comment: why doesn't it reset after reboot?

Comment: because it is stored in the registry and linked ot the network configuration (IP settings). Mostly to default gatway IP.

Comment: just out of curiosity, do you know where it is stored?

Comment: RegEdit->Edit->Find->Enter the name and wait when it found it.